# APNS not working with Adhoc build

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I am using an application with Adhoc Provisioning profile and certificate. The application is not yet published. But the APNS is giving an error **8-Invalid Token**

Following things are already checked.

1. Application has the entitlement key `<aps_environment>production<aps_environment>`, checked from the mobile.embeddedprovision
2. APNS SSL Certificate was generated by selecting an option Create **Sandbox or Production SSL Certificate**
3. The certificate itself can connect to Production
4. The APNS url used in Php script is
   ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
5. All the old tokens from cleared from the db and the test was done with the new token

What else should I check I am really running out of ideas...

Could this happen because the Application is not published to the App Store?

Comment: did u fix it???